# How to return a FileResult using an Amazon S3 ResponseStream?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, stream

Using the AWSSDK.S3 nuget package, I'm trying to return a file that has been retrieved from an S3 bucket. My starting point is based on the example given in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402735/streaming-files-from-amazon-s3).

Example controller code:

```
public FileResult GetFile(Guid id)
{
    // no using block as it will be disposed of by the File method
    var amazonResponse = _foo.GetAmazonResponseWrapper(_user, id);
    // set Response content-length header
    // set Response content-type header

    var bufferSize = 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = amazonResponse.ResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0 && Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    }        

    // this will not work (can't read from this stream)
    return File(Response.OutputStream, "text/plain", "bar.txt");
}
```

If I write to a `MemoryStream` I create and use in the `while` loop, I will get a file, but there won't be any content.

The only way I've found to get content in the file is to call `.ToArray()` on the stream like so:

```
return File(memStream.ToArray(), "text/plain", "foo.txt");
```

Is there a way to actually stream a file to the browser without loading it into the memory of the web server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the stream forward

```
public FileResult GetFile(Guid id) {
    // no using block as it will be disposed of by the File method
    var amazonResponse = _foo.GetAmazonResponseWrapper(_user, id);
    return File(amazonResponse.ResponseStream, "text/plain", "bar.txt");
}
```

You have already shown that you can read from the response stream. Then just pass the response stream on and the File result will read it and return the response.

Comment: This seems like one of those "It's so obviously simple it has to work this way" situations. I wasn't sure of the reasoning for using an intermediate stream as I'm new to the AWS world. I'll give this a go and revisit this question tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Sure. It just seemed to be controller code using the HttpResponse object.

Comment: @Jecoms, I stand corrected. It was probably for an earlier version.

Comment: Looks to be working just fine; it's simple and (should've been) intuitive. The only thing I'm unclear on is how it handles content-length. For now, I added a header for it using `Response.AddHeader()`, but I'm not sure if it's necessary. (The `GetObjectResponse` object returned from the S3 SDK has this info.)

Comment: @Jecoms The inner workings of the action result will get the content length from the length of the stream